# Have an error when downloading tensorflow-gpu==2.4.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uCjb.png)

reported as
'Could not fetch URL https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple/tensorflow-gpu/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/tensorflow-gpu/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1125)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==2.4.0
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu==2.4.0'

cuda==11.0.2 cudnn=8.0 python==3.8.6 pip==21.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow has included the gpu version in its `tensorflow` package for version 2. https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

you can just do `pip install tensorflow==2.4.0` now, and you will get the gpu version.